# Angular 4/5 DOM update and change detection

Tags: angular, dom

Whenever Change Detection locates a component whose template needs DOM update (e.g. due to a binding), **what exactly comes next**? By which mechanism and how DOM is informed? Also, does it wait till the end of Change Detection cycle as to `send all the required DOM changes together`? Could someone give me a basic description or suggest some relevant resources since I cannot find something appropriate...

Comment: Maybe [the documentation on lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lifecycle hook method in Angular 5 here is the link https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks you can use it
ngDoCheck() method:- Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its own.

Called during every change detection run, immediately after ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit